# Split long definition into two slides

Tags: beamer, split, slideshow

I want to make a slide with `beamer`. I have long definition to show in a slide. I want to split it into 2 slides. How to split the long definition into 2 slides? I don't know to do it.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, 10pt,notheorems]{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Red]{structure}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definisi}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\begin{document}

\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\section{RUANG VEKTOR ATAS FIELD}
\begin{frame}{RUANG VEKTOR ATAS FIELD}
\begin{definition}\normalfont
    Misalkan $\mathbb{F}$ adalah field dan $V$ adalah himpunan tak kosong yang dilengkapi operasi biner penjumlahan dan perkalian terhadap skalar. $V$ disebut ruang vektor atas field $\mathbb{F}$ jika memenuhi sepuluh aksioma berikut.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Tertutup terhadap penjumlahan\\
        Untuk setiap $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\in V$, berlaku $\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}\in V$.
        \item Komutatif terhadap penjumlahan\\
        Untuk setiap $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\in V$, berlaku $\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{u}$.
        \item Asosiatif terhadap penjumlahan\\
        Untuk setiap $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\in V$, berlaku $(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v})+\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{u}+(\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w})$.
        \item Memiliki identitas penjumlahan\\
        Terdapat $\mathbf{0}\in V$ sedemikian sehingga untuk setiap $\mathbf{u}\in V$ berlaku $\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{u}$.
        \item Setiap vektor mempunyai invers penjumlahan\\
        Untuk setiap $\mathbf{u}\in V$, terdapat $-\mathbf{u}\in V$  sedemikian sehingga 
        berlaku $\mathbf{u}+(-\mathbf{u})=-\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0}$.
        \item Tertutup terhadap perkalian skalar\\
        Untuk setiap $\mathbf{u}\in V$ dan $k\in\mathbb{F}$, berlaku $k\mathbf{u}\in V$.
        \item Distributif perkalian skalar dengan penjumlahan vektor\\
        Untuk setiap $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\in V$ dan $k\in\mathbb{F}$, berlaku $k(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v})=k\mathbf{u}+k\mathbf{v}$.
        \item Distributif perkalian dari penjumlahan skalar dengan vektor\\
        Untuk setiap $\mathbf{u}\in V$ dan $k,l\in\mathbb{F}$, berlaku $(k+l)\mathbf{u}=k\mathbf{u}+l\mathbf{u}$.
        \item Asosiatif terhadap perkalian skalar dengan vektor\\
        Untuk setiap $\mathbf{u}\in V$ dan $k,l\in\mathbb{F}$, berlaku $(kl)\mathbf{u}=k(l\mathbf{u})$.
        \item Perkalian dengan skalar $1\in\mathbb{F}$\\
        Untuk setiap $\mathbf{u}\in V$ berlaku $1\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{u}$.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do here, unconventionally is to place the complete definition in a saved `\vbox` and use `\clipbox` to slice it into two pieces, one for each frame.  In order for the `\savebox` to be available within the scope of both frames, I had to save the box *outside* of the frame itself.  This introduced an added complication of an undefined variable `\beamer@cramped`, which I had to disable at the onset of the `\savebox`.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, 10pt,notheorems]{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Red]{structure}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definisi}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{trimclip}
\newsavebox\mydef
\begin{document}

\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\section{RUANG VEKTOR ATAS FIELD}
\makeatletter
\savebox\mydef{\let\beamer@cramped\relax\vbox{%
\begin{definition}\normalfont
    Misalkan $\mathbb{F}$ adalah field dan $V$ adalah himpunan tak kosong yang dilengkapi operasi biner penjumlahan dan perkalian terhadap skalar. $V$ disebut ruang vektor atas field $\mathbb{F}$ jika memenuhi sepuluh aksioma berikut.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Tertutup terhadap penjumlahan\\
        Untuk setiap $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\in V$, berlaku $\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}\in V$.
        \item Komutatif terhadap penjumlahan\\
        Untuk setiap $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\in V$, berlaku $\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{u}$.
        \item Asosiatif terhadap penjumlahan\\
        Untuk setiap $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\in V$, berlaku $(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v})+\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{u}+(\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w})$.
        \item Memiliki identitas penjumlahan\\
        Terdapat $\mathbf{0}\in V$ sedemikian sehingga untuk setiap $\mathbf{u}\in V$ berlaku $\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{u}$.
        \item Setiap vektor mempunyai invers penjumlahan\\
        Untuk setiap $\mathbf{u}\in V$, terdapat $-\mathbf{u}\in V$  sedemikian sehingga 
        berlaku $\mathbf{u}+(-\mathbf{u})=-\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0}$.
        \item Tertutup terhadap perkalian skalar\\
        Untuk setiap $\mathbf{u}\in V$ dan $k\in\mathbb{F}$, berlaku $k\mathbf{u}\in V$.
        \item Distributif perkalian skalar dengan penjumlahan vektor\\
        Untuk setiap $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\in V$ dan $k\in\mathbb{F}$, berlaku $k(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v})=k\mathbf{u}+k\mathbf{v}$.
        \item Distributif perkalian dari penjumlahan skalar dengan vektor\\
        Untuk setiap $\mathbf{u}\in V$ dan $k,l\in\mathbb{F}$, berlaku $(k+l)\mathbf{u}=k\mathbf{u}+l\mathbf{u}$.
        \item Asosiatif terhadap perkalian skalar dengan vektor\\
        Untuk setiap $\mathbf{u}\in V$ dan $k,l\in\mathbb{F}$, berlaku $(kl)\mathbf{u}=k(l\mathbf{u})$.
        \item Perkalian dengan skalar $1\in\mathbb{F}$\\
        Untuk setiap $\mathbf{u}\in V$ berlaku $1\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{u}$.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{definition}
}}
\makeatother
\begin{frame}{RUANG VEKTOR ATAS FIELD}
\clipbox{0pt 180pt 0pt 0pt}{\usebox\mydef}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\clipbox{0pt 0pt 0pt \dimexpr\ht\mydef-180pt\relax}{\usebox\mydef}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]